# Boto3 some image objects downloading, some displayed inline

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am running a code to upload files to S3 using boto3 -

```
client = boto3.client('s3',region_name='us-west-1')
    client.upload_file("FILENAME","BUCKETNAME","OBJECTNAME",ExtraArgs={'Metadata': {'Content-Type': 'image/png'}})
    bucket_location = boto3.client('s3').get_bucket_location(Bucket="BUCKETNAME")
    url2 = "https://{0}.s3.{1}.amazonaws.com/{2}".format("BUCKETNAME",bucket_location['LocationConstraint'],"OBJECTNAME")
```

For the URLs that I am getting in the url2 list, some are being downloaded whereas some are being displayed in-browser. I want to display all of them in-browser.
I have manually selected all objects in S3, and edited Content-Type to image/png, and have also tried adding Content-Disposition as "inline". Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it was a caching problem on my end. After clearing the cache, all the images are displayed inline.